# Print Preview Template Specific Area of page in .php file

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

When user clicks print this page, I want to show a div as a Print Page template. I have a `.php` file. I tried :

```
<a class="printer" href="javascript:window.print("printArea")">Print this Page</a>

<div id="printArea"> 
    Some stuff to print
</div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/print  the function accepts no arguments. If you want only a particular section to print, you'll have to define a`media:print` style sheet that hides everything else.